# Cannot get static files from express static middleware

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to serve images.

this is the endpoint (which I have modified to use "/backend" and many other combinations that did not work):

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
```

this is "__dirname + '/uploads'":

> C:\Users\jack7\OneDrive\Documents\Programming Projects\30 days of React\BlogProject\backend/uploads

this is the path to my img:

> C:\Users\jack7\OneDrive\Documents\Programming Projects\30 days of React\BlogProject\BackEnd\uploads\71d1d5f8cb5ed5a9401764de2cf0b546.jpg

this is my request url and error:

> GET http://localhost:5000/backend/uploads/71d1d5f8cb5ed5a9401764de2cf0b546.jpg 404 (Not Found)

The only possible issues I have found are related to casing and reconciliation of the use of both forward and back slashes in paths, which seems to be auto-corrected anyways. I am not really sure how much context and what context to use for explaining this problem, so please let me know. I hope there is something obviously wrong with the code and logic I provided.

Comment: In the path to the image you provided, the folder name is "BackEnd" with a capital "E". Are you sure that's the correct path?

Comment: renamed all mentions of backend to be lowercase, including the path, and still no the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
 app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));
```

Try :

```
const path = require('path');
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')))
```

From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-express-static-function/

---

- Maybe the set up is not right, your mixing windows and linux paths. (edit :mixing forward and back slashes is fine, backend takes care of it)
- Also try not to keep any spaces in your folder names. Try this in `c:\prog\react\project2` or some such folder
- In linux like programs path case has to be preseved. So use what is the actual captitilzation, copy it.
- Tip : To copy path in windows: can press shift, right click and go down to Copy path i windows see https://www.thewindowsclub.com/path-copy-copy-lets-you-copy-file-paths or https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/articles/00015251

Comment: This worked when I used "/backend/uploads" as the route prefix. Thank you. Also it seems that both "/" and "\" are valid even within a single windows path, because they were all converted for me despite using both. I will keep those things in mind though thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're requesting `localhost:5000/backend/uploads/`, but you're serving uploads on the `/uploads` URL path.

You should just need to send a GET request to `localhost:5000/uploads/71d1d5f8cb5ed5a9401764de2cf0b546.jpg`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The path would not save into the db AND upload to the uploads folder unless I included "backend" in the path. I don't see why I can't just accommodate and make the get req to /backend/uploads or whatever (which I tried and failed at).

Comment: `I don't see why I can't just accommodate and make the get req to /backend/uploads` Because you specified `/uploads` as your http path prefix.

Comment: That is just for example in this post, sorry for the confusion. I have specified "/backend/uploads" as the path and it solves nothing.